# How can I load changes to my .emacs without rebooting Emacs?

Tags: configuration, emacs

How can I load changes from .emacs without rebooting Emacs?

Comment: Hi, Zubair here. Even though my question is marked as a duplicate of yours for some reason yours has less votes. Anyway, in good faith I just upvoted yours too!